# Help with question from Chiswell and Hodges

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working through *Mathematical Logic* by Chiswell and Hodges and I'm confused by exercise 2.5.1(d) (pg. 23).

Give derivations to prove the following sequents:
.
.
.
(d) $((A \leftrightarrow (B \leftrightarrow C)) \leftrightarrow ((A \leftrightarrow B) \leftrightarrow C))$

I see that it's clearly true, but the proof I'm finding is about 5 times longer than the proofs for any of the other exercises so far in the book (and a little further). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm guessing the book wants you to derive this from successively applying laws of inference? In which case it will probably be a mess. It's clearly true, but how short is your own proof?

Comment: You might want to try deriving things like the commutivity and transitivity of $\iff$ first, then establish the truth of $X \iff X$,then establish $(A \iff A) \iff (B \iff B) \iff (C \iff C)$.

Comment: I do not know your proof, but I think that it will be very simple but quite long and boring; you have to "unpack" all the bi-conditional and use multiple $\to$-elim and $\to$-intro...

Comment: I'd doubt you've missed much.  I've proved this in a natural deduction and axiomatic context before, here is *one* example: http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/most-difficult-logic-derivation-34831-2.html and proving the association of <-> tends to get long.

Comment: I had the same problem as you (just now), and have just found out that this problem _cannot_ be done from the rules established so far.  Read the author's corrigenda: http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/corrigml.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Wanna put it in an answer so you can get the credit?

Answer (score 2):

> For : $(A↔(B↔C)) \vdash ((A↔B)↔C)$

*First part* :

1) $(A↔(B↔C))$ --- premise

2) $C$ --- assumed [a]

3) $A$ --- assumed [b]

4) $B \to A$ --- from 3) by $\to$-intro

5) $A \to (B↔C)$ --- from 1) by $↔$-elim

6) $(B↔C)$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\to$-elim

7) $C \to B$ --- from 6) by $↔$-elim

8) $B$ --- from 2) and 7) by $\to$-elim

9) $A \to B$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

10) $(A↔B)$ --- from 4) and 9) by $↔$-intro

> 11) $C \to (A↔B)$ --- from 2) and 10) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

*Second part* (this is the only way I've found):

1) $(A↔(B↔C))$ --- premise

2) $(A↔B)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $A \lor \lnot A$ --- Excluded Middle

4) $A$ --- assumed [b] (for $\lor$-elim)

5) $A \to B$ --- from 2)

6) $B$ --- from 4) and 5)

7) $(B↔C)$ --- from 4) and 1)

8) $B \to C$ --- from 7)

9) $C$ --- from 6) and 8)

10) $\lnot A$ --- assumed [c] (for $\lor$-elim)

11) $B$ --- assumed [d]

12) $C \to B$ --- from 11) by $\to$-intro

13) $B \to A$ --- from 2)

14) $A$ --- from 11) and 13)

15) $\bot$ --- from 10) and 14)

16) $C$ --- from 15)

17) $B \to C$ --- from 11) and 16) by $\to$-intro, discharging [d]

18) $(B↔C)$ --- from 12) and 17)

19) $A$ --- from 1) and 18) by $↔$-elim and $\to$-elim

20) $\bot$ --- from 10) and 19)

21) $C$ --- from 20)

22) $C$ --- from 4)-9) and 10)-21) and 3) by $\lor$-elim, discharging [b] and [c]

> 23) $(A↔B) \to C$ --- from 2) and 22) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

> > $(A↔B) ↔ C$ --- from 11) and 23) by $↔$-intro.

Comment: You discharge (3) A into (A -> B).  Then you use (4) (B -> A) which relied on the hypothesis (3) A in the next step.  I don't see how that is legal.

Comment: Also, at step 10 in the first part, you infer (A <-> B) from 4) and 9).  But 4) happened under the scope of assumption 3).  That's like saying you could adjoin an arbitrary hypothesis (p -> q) or 'p' to the theorem set under the empty set of hypotheses.  In the second part at step 18) you again used (C -> B) to get to (B <-> C) AFTER you had discharged the hypothesis B used to derive (C -> B).  If we did that, then if we derived CpCCpqq, then had p, and Cpq in some sub-proof with a hypothesis, then we could infer q as a theorem.  Then we can interpret q as falsity, and logic is inconsistent.

Comment: Suppose our assumption is KpCpq.  We can then get both p, and also Cpq by conjunction elimination.  We can then infer CKpCpqCpq with p and Cpq not qualify as discharged.  But, if p can get used even after getting discharged, then p is a theorem.  So, falsity would have to qualify as a theorem of classical logic.  Since CKpCpqCpq evaluates to true, that would render classical logic inconsistent.  Chiswell and Hodges don't use any deduced assumptions within the scope of an assumption after the assumption has gotten discharged.  Please point out an instance of where they do so if I am wrong.

Comment: Though maybe you meant the steps pointed out as hints instead of complete deductions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the presence of 2.5.9. (d) in its place in the book is a mistake. By the end of section 2.5, one knows only the following rules of deduction:

(∧I), (∧E), (→I), (→E), (↔I), (↔E)

It is impossible to do with such a limited toolset. This impossibility can be proven using the method of exercise 3.9.2, using three-value logic as normally in 3.9.2 with additional definitions:

A*((φ∧ψ)) = min(A*(φ),A*(ψ))

A*((φ↔ψ)) = A*((φ→ψ)∧(ψ→φ))

And showing that adding rules (∧I), (∧E),(↔I), (↔E) does not affect the validity of the claim in exercise 3.9.2 step (c).

Then, let's  assume A*(φ) = A*(ψ) = 0 and A*(χ) = 1/2. The A* value of the whole formula from 2.5.9(d) equals 1/2, which is less than 1, so any derivation of this formula using only the toolset one knows by finishing reading section 2.5 would need an undischarged assumpiton.

Comment: esotechnica already had this point in a comment above:
"I had the same problem as you (just now), and have just found out that this problem cannot be done from the rules established so far. Read the author's corrigenda: wilfridhodges.co.uk/corrigml.pdf "